# Connect CodeIgniter 3 with SQL server

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I'm currently using CodeIgniter 3.0.6 for my project.
I need to connect my webapp with a MS sql server. That's my situation:

PHP version: 5.6 on locahost and 5.4 on us intranet.

Sql version: MS Windows Server 2008 R2

I've already installed on both server all DLL ext

PHP 5.6

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

PHP 5.4

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dl
```

On my CI configuration DB I have:

```
'dsn'       => '',
'hostname'  => 'MYHOST',
'username'  => 'USER',
'password'  => 'PSW',
'database'  => 'DB',
'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
```

but I've also tried

```
'dsn' => 'sqlsrv:server=HOST,1433;Database=DBNAME',
'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
'subdriver' => 'pdo'
```

Always I have the same error:

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/system/database/DB_driver.php
Line Number: 436
```

I've read a lot of tutorial and question here on stackoverflow but all doens't work.

Help me please to find a solution, I'm gettin crazy!

Comment: try dbdriver as pdo not sqlsrv

Comment: Still have problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've a project with MSSQL Server (Navision as an ERP behind of that) and CI.
We had huge troubles with the official (sick!) driver from Microsoft and had problems with the 64 bit environment too;

After long research we found an unofficial release - read the posts of the following links. It worked like a charm for us:

[How to install Microsoft's SQL Server Driver for PHP](http://robsphp.blogspot.co.at/2012/09/how-to-install-microsofts-sql-server.html)

[Unofficial Microsoft SQL Server Driver for PHP (sqlsrv)](http://robsphp.blogspot.co.at/2012/06/unofficial-microsoft-sql-server-driver.html)